# How to access a TypeScript definition that is within a module?

Tags: node.js, types, module, typescript

I'm trying to type something a the 'Url' object that is described within the [NodeJS definition](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/node). But the 'Url' object is described under the 'url' module. Because it's under the module its not recognised by the compiler as a valid type.

```
///<reference path='../../../Definitions/node.d.ts' />
///<reference path='../../../Definitions/node-webkit.d.ts' />
///<reference path='../../../Definitions/cheerio.d.ts' />

var NodeUrl = require('url');

function findLinks($cheerio:Cheerio, internalOnly?:boolean, rootUrl?:url.Url):string[] {
    //url.Url is not recognised, neither is Url or NodeUrl.Url
}
```

The definition file is defining the following module (alongside the rest of NodeJS):

```
declare module "url" {
    export interface Url {
        href: string;
        protocol: string;
        auth: string;
        hostname: string;
        port: string;
        host: string;
        pathname: string;
        search: string;
        query: any; // string | Object
        slashes: boolean;
        hash?: string;
        path?: string;
    }

    export interface UrlOptions {
        protocol?: string;
        auth?: string;
        hostname?: string;
        port?: string;
        host?: string;
        pathname?: string;
        search?: string;
        query?: any;
        hash?: string;
        path?: string;
    }

    export function parse(urlStr: string, parseQueryString?: boolean , slashesDenoteHost?: boolean ): Url;
    export function format(url: UrlOptions): string;
    export function resolve(from: string, to: string): string;
}
```

How do I reference the Url type correctly?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Typescript you need to use slightly different syntax to import modules:

```
import NodeURL = require('url');
```

You will now be able to access

```
NodeURL.Url
```